# symbols not found in static library even though they are there

Tags: linker, static-libraries, linker-errors, symbols, ld

I am trying to build TerraGear from the FlightGear project, and it needs multiple symbols from a static library `libSimGearBucket` upon linking, for example `SGBucket::gen_base_path`. `ld` fails with

```sh
warning: undefined reference to »SGBucket::gen_base_path[abi:cxx11]() const
```

These are defined in the library:

```sh
$ nm libSimGearCore.a | grep gen_base_path
00000000000001f0 T _ZNK8SGBucket13gen_base_pathEv
                 U _ZNK8SGBucket13gen_base_pathEv
                 U _ZNK8SGBucket13gen_base_pathEv
```

I made triple sure that library ***is*** linked to the program needing the symbols. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you *need* is `SGBucket::gen_base_path[abi:cxx11]() const`.

The function you *have* is `SGBucket::gen_base_path() const`. These aren't the same symbol.

You can use `-Wl,--no-demangle` at link time to tell the linker to print *mangled* (real) symbol that ends up undefined, and that would make it clearer that you don't in fact have a definition of that symbol.

Possibly the `libSimGearCore.a` library was compiled without `-std=c++11` flag, while the code which needs the symbol was compiled with it.

Comment: CAn you explain why that symbols appears three times in nm's output ? Two times as U, and once as T.

Comment: @Programmer This is normal. Run `nm -A libSimGearCore.a | grep gen_base_path` and it will become obvious why this is happening.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to fix this: nm without -D shows all symbols, but nm with -D shows none ? Do I have to recompile everything and add some switch, or what …

Comment: @Programmer This is also normal: `nm -D` shows symbols that the _dynamic_ linker will interpret. There are no such symbols in archive libraries, they only occur in executables and shared libraries.